# Custom hasMany Relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
public function chats()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chat','sender_id')->orWhere('receiver_id',\Auth::id());
}
```

My requirement is that i want to fetch messages that being sent or received by User.  how i can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick:

```
public function chats()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Chat','sender_id')->union($this->hasMany('App\Chat','receiver_id'));
}
```

This will return a relation that is a **union** of 2 queries - one that fetches chat messages where given user is the sender and another one where given user is the receiver.

You can now access user's chats with **$user->chats**.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. `hasMany()` accepts chained `where()` and `orWhere()` calls, so I would make that query like this:

```
public function chats()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chat')
        ->where('sender_id', \Auth::id())
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', \Auth::id());
}
```

Once this is correctly set up, you can use `$users->chats` to access a list of chats that were sent from OR to the current user.

Comment: I dont think this will work. By default, hasMany will try and join on chats.user_id as the default foreign key. If you chat record does not have a user_id field, it will fail.